# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException' when no changes have been made since it was last working?

Tags: xcode4.5

I have not made any changes to either ViewController since it was last working. I am now getting this error.

> 2012-11-02 15:15:14.206 App[15247:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key phone.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1d86012 0x11c3e7e 0x1e0efb1 0xc70711 0xbf1ec8 0xbf19b7 0xc1c428 0x3280cc 0x11d7663 0x1d8145a 0x326bcf 0x1ebe37 0x1ec418 0x1ec648 0x1ec882 0x27f4 0x11d7705 0x10e920 0x10e8b8 0x1cf671 0x1cfbcf 0x1ced38 0x13e33f 0x13e552 0x11c3aa 0x10dcf8 0x1ce1df9 0x1ce1ad0 0x1cfbbf5 0x1cfb962 0x1d2cbb6 0x1d2bf44 0x1d2be1b 0x1ce07e3 0x1ce0668 0x10b65c 0x2052 0x1f85 0x1)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Can anyone help finding what has changed and gone wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more useful to see the stack trace with symbols...but the usual reason for this is that there's something in a xib or storyboard file that makes reference to an outlet that doesn't exist in code.  If that's true in your case, it looks as if the outlet is named `phone`.

(I'm a bit surprised that it just says "this class" rather than telling you which one it's upset about.)

Comment: I find it weird that this is marked as "too localized" and "unlikely to help future visitors." I just got this exception and @Phillip's answer is correct--I personally deleted an IBOutlet in my code but forgot to remove it in the Connections Inspector in Xcode.